# Can't install igraph package in R

Tags: r, igraph

I can't install igraph package for R, the error message is below

> - installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
>     ** package ‘igraph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
>     checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>     checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>     checking for suffix of executables... 
>     checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>     checking for suffix of object files... o
>     checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>     checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
>     checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>     checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
>     checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
>     checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
>     checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
>     configure: error: no C++ compiler found or it cannot create executables
>     ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’

The g++ and gcc are installed.

Comment: Are you able to install other packages from source? Also, what happens when you type `gcc --version` from a terminal window?

Comment: @LenGreski Yes, I can install other packages from source, and gcc --version will show the version infomation of gcc

Comment: If you can install other packages from source, you should probably report this as an issue on the [igraph github issues page](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu linux (derivative) Install:

`sudo apt-get install gfortan-7 libblas-dev liblapack-dev`

I might suggest also checking:

`gcc --version`
`g++ --version`

To make sure you have these installed as well.

One rant: The error messages for installing `igraph` are horrid.